# MacBook Pro 2020 13 Inch Powering Off When Closing Lid

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, power

Every time I close my lid on my MacBook Pro it powers off completely. When I turn it back on, it gives me a something went wrong error. I was getting a `"sleep wake failure"` error before. It's a brand new computer and I've done a hard reset already. I deleted the "sleepimage" file from `/private/var/VM/` as recommended in another post. I still have this issue. Any help would be appreciated.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What information is displayed when you click the "Report" button?

Comment: What's the version of macOS that you are running? Add it to the question, I had a similar issue with this with the new update as it added the battery heath feature - which I turned off.

Comment: macOS Catalina 10.15.5. One second David I have the report saved in an email. I can't seem to reproduce it.

Comment: I added the photo of the report @David

Comment: Create a new use profile, log out with your regular account, and log in with the new profile. Does the misbehavior occur? Have you tried restoring the OS?

Comment: Yes. Restored OS and wiped the drive.

Comment: That the misbehavior continues after those two tests suggests it's a hardware issue. As a 2020 model, at least in the US, your machine should still be under warranty.